# toggling buttons and panels using twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three buttons and each triggers showing a corresponding panel. I would like to only show one panel at a time, but right now a panel is shown per button clicked. So clicking all three buttons shows three panels at the same time.

I am using twitter bootstrap, and this is my code:

```
 <span data-toggle="buttons-radio">
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-white pull-right m-r"  data-toggle="class:show" href="#content1"><i class="icon-sitemap"></i> Content1</a>
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-white pull-right m-r" data-toggle="class:show" href="#content2"><i class="icon-user"></i> Content2</a>
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right m-r"  data-toggle="class:show" href="#content3"><i class="icon-male"></i><i class="icon-female"></i> Content3</a>
</span>

<aside class="bg-white hide col-lg-6 b-l" id="content1">
 <div>
    <h2>This is content 1</h2>
 </div>
</aside>

<aside class="bg-white hide col-lg-6 b-l" id="content2">
 <div>
    <h2>This is content 2</h2>
 </div>
</aside>

<aside class="bg-white hide col-lg-6 b-l" id="content3">
 <div>
    <h2>This is content 3</h2>
 </div>
</aside>
```

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap, tabs work that way:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

The tabs titles show up across the top and clicking them shows different content. Two tabs are never shown at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a .btn-group to your span.

```
<span class="btn-group">
  //your buttons
</span>
```